# Select cells (buttons) on diagonals of a square matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, animation

I'm writing wpf music pad application, where I have 16 button (Here is an example of real music pad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vC5TsSyNjU).

Each button plays different music sample. This works well. 
But when user is in idle, I want to create simple animation shown in the image below.

[image]

Animation starts from button 1 (animates it's background color to white, then goes back to original color).

Here is the steps of animation:

- step 1: animate buttons: 1
- step 2: animate buttons: 2, Q
- step 3: animate buttons: 3, W, A
- step 4: animate buttons: 4, E, S, Z
- step 5: animate buttons: R, D, X
- step 6: animate buttons: F, C
- step 7: animate buttons: V

I created function *AnimatePad* which takes button and starts background color animation after specified time. This function works as expected.

To implement the steps described above, I'm calling *AnimatePad* function for each button. Here is the code which I'm currently using  and this is what I want to improve. I currently have hard coded this steps. If my buttons count changes, I must go back and change this code, which is a bad idea.

```
        double beginMs = 0;
        var spd = 300;
        var interval = 40;
        var toColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[0], toColor);

        beginMs += interval;
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[1], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[4], toColor);

        beginMs += interval;                
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[2], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[5], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[8], toColor);

        beginMs += interval;                
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[3], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[6], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[9], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[12], toColor);

        beginMs += interval;                 
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[7], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[10], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[13], toColor);

        beginMs += interval;                 
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[11], toColor);
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[14], toColor);

        beginMs += interval;                
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[15], toColor);
```

So I want more generic way to choose buttons for animation.

I'm sure there must be some algorithm. Thank you!

Comment: your `pads` should be some square array, it would be easier. Otherwise we have to determine the number of columns from just the total number of buttons (which in fact has many cases, such as 4x4, 2x8, 8x2), if the rows number = columns number, we can use `Math.Sqrt` but using square array is better.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine indexes of elements on given diagonal of rectangular matrix?

Comment: Or if you just looking to improve your current code consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: No I want to determine indexes in generic way. pads always will be square array.

Comment: @WaterDance, Please check if you are ok with my edit of title, feel free to improve (or revert, also I don't think original title clearly specified what you are looking for).

Comment: Yes it looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var n = (int) Math.Sqrt(pads.Length);
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   k = i;
   AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[k], toColor);
   for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
      k += n-1;          
      AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[k], toColor);
   }
   beginMs += interval;
}
for(i = n-2; i >= 0; i--){       
   k = (n-i)*n - 1;
   AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[k], toColor);
   for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
      k += n-1;
      AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pads[k], toColor);
   }
   beginMs += interval;
}
```

Comment: The input check supposes `pads.Length` should be a square of some number, such as `4`, `9`, `16`, `25`, ...

Comment: nope. Didn't worked. I casted n to int. But animation order is incorrect.

Comment: @WaterDance the algorithm seems right to me, it does not animate at all? or animated in wrong order?

Comment: @WaterDance could you check what the exact order it's currently animating?

Comment: It animates in wrong order. first is 1, then 2, Q, R which is incorrect.

Comment: @WaterDance I've just changed `j <= i` to `j < i`, please check it.

Comment: I tried. First 3 step is correct but is does not animates from R, D, X

Comment: @WaterDance check my update. I did not think it's a bit complicated like that. Maybe there is some better algorithm, if finding something better, I'll notify you.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine 2d array with indexes and sum of their indexes. 
If you add each button's indexes you will get the sum. 
For example, *0,0* item's sum is 0. *2,1* index sum is 3 and so on.

On step 1 select buttons which has index sum 0, On step 2 select buttons which has index sum 1, etc.

[image]

I don't know what the type of pads array is. If they are only buttons array, then I suggest to create complex type. For example:

```
public class PadItem
{
    public Button Pad {get; set; }
    public int IndexSum {get; set; }
}
```

Here is the sample:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    var stepPads = pads.Where(p => p.IndexSum == i);
    beginMs += interval;
    foreach (var pad in stepPads)
    {
        AnimatePad(ref beginMs, spd, pad, toColor);
    }
}
```